# kill subprocess using signal.CTRL_C_EVENT without killing main

Tags: python, python-unittest

**How can I kill a subprocess without also killing **main**?**

I have a subprocess that can only be killed with `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT`. Performing the standard `os.kill(my_pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` kills the process but also causes my main to die despite having a differnet pid.

My ultimate goal is to create the subprocess from within a unit test so i need the unit test to return `sys.exit(0)` after passing all tests.

**child.py**

```
from time

while True:
  print "I am alive"
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

**parent.py**

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(["child.py"], shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
os.kill(p.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)

print("This line doesn't print because the main thread dies")
```

::: update :::

I am trying to run this in Windows. removing `shell=True` has no apparent effect. I am seeing a KeyboardInterrupt error in parent.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last)    
    File "parent.py", line 23, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
```

All of the following methods result in this same behavior

- `os.kill`
- send signal on `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).children()`
- `subprocess.call(['taskkill', ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are on Windows. That is an important distinction here. It also appears you are using Python2.

On Windows, `os.kill` has some *really* strange behavior. I'd suggest not even trying to use it, unless you are trying to give yourself a headache. Try usingf `psutil` (in the parent):

```
    children = psutil.Process(os.getpid()).children()
    for c in children:
        c.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
    psutil.wait_procs(children)
```

alternately, you can call `taskkill`:

```
subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/PID', str(child.pid)])
```

Comment: yes this is on windows. Both methods are still killing main

Comment: do both methods end up killing main *and* the child process? This is sounding like it's not even truly starting a new process. Try this: start both the child and the main process like you are doing, but add a print statement to each of them that prints their own PID. In the parent, have it also print what it *thinks* is the PID of the child. And have both of them sleep for a long enough time to allow you to look in Task Manager and see if those PID's seem to match what is reported.

Comment: also try getting rid of the `shell=True`, that option is extremely platform dependent in a way that can give strange results. You might need to change the way you call `popen` to give the full path to your python interpreter executable, and then the full path to the `child.py` file.

Comment: I added an `:::update:::` in my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the byte `0x03` to the child process's standard input (stdin). This is the byte used to indicate a Ctrl+C signal.

Comment: Maybe windows is different, but in UNIX signals are not delivered via standard IO streams. The mechanisms the kernel uses to deliver signals depend on what signal is sent, how (and if) the program is configured to handle certain signals, and a number of other factors. In the end, it usually involves the kernel performing some direct and complicated modifications to the programs memory space to invoke the correct response.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know this. Thank you for informing me!